# How to handle redux-form/CHANGE in reducer

Tags: redux-form

What is the recommended way to handle `redux-form/CHANGE` actions being dispatched by redux-form? I have my own reducer managing the state of this form but I'm not sure if it's best to do the following:

```
export default reducer (state = initialState, action) {
  case 'redux-form/CHANGE':
    // return modified state
}
```

One problem I see is that this reducer would receive *every* `redux-form/CHANGE` action. Additionally as far as I can tell ActionTypes.js isn't exported in a way for me to import it so I feel as though this may not be best practice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can definitely use `redux-form` action creators. You just have to connect it to your component.

So in your `/components/MyComponent.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { change } from 'redux-form';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    ...
    render() {
        return <div>
            <button onClick={this.props.change('formName', 'fieldName', 'value')}>Change</button>
        </div>
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => { ... }
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { change })(MyComponent);
```

You could also use `redux-form` reducer and extends it to your needs...

In your `reducers/index.js`]

```
import { reducer as form } from 'redux-form';

const formPlugin = {
    formName: (state, action) => {
        ...reducer logic
        return newState;
    }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    ...other reducers,
    form: form.plugin(formPlugin)
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have a solution for my similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46461103/how-to-stop-redux-forms-form-state-from-auto-rehydrated-by-redux-persit